# Send an SSRS report by email using an SQL Job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm new working with SSRS Suscriptions and I would like to know how can I resolve this problem since I had investigate but not find somenthing like this.

I have this table in SQL (Products table) that is filled with new products daily at random times, my SSRS report shows all the data from that table (id, name, description, etc.), the thing is that I want this SSRS report to be send to my email everytime a new product is registred in the Products table.

My first thought is making a Job in SQL that every 5 minutes checks the Products table, counts the products, saves that value and when the value changes then sends the email, but I don't know how to do that.

Something like:

if (@OldValue <> @NewValue) BEGIN
**execute ssrs_name and send to email@email.com**
End

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Sure you have a create date and time on your product table? It would be as simple as writing a query to filter all products created within the last X minutes and a report based on that. Create a subscription for the same and email it to you

Comment: Harry, yes, the table has a datetime column but  the time gets set to 0:0:00, so I can really use it, that's why I was thinking on counting the rows or maybe use the id of the products, since it is an autoincrement column

Answer (score 1):

Create an "AFTER INSERT" trigger that send the email whenever a new row is created.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fc95e317-ee8b-4393-9bbd-7c32f30cff75/run-a-report-based-on-new-record-in-table?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Seems like a great solution! Will it work the same if I try it with not a table but an SP that generates a resulset with info of different tables?

Comment: Yes, you can use a trigger to execute an SP without issue.